# 8:1 Multiplexer With 5 Parameters of F(A,B,C,D,E) = ABCD +B'CDE+BC'D'

Tags: multiplexer

I am trying to create a multiplexer 8:1 with 5 parameters of the function $$F(A,B,C,D,E) = ABCD +B'CDE+BC'D'$$
what I did its to right it as minterms so what I get is:
$$ F = ABCDE + ABCDE' + AB'CDE + A'B'CDE + ABC'D'E' + A'BC'D'E \rightarrow m(31,30,23,7,24,9)$$
now what I need to do? I need some advice how to continue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're taking only works if you have a 32:1 multiplexer with 5 select inputs.

If what you have is an 8:1 multiplexer with 3 select inputs, you need to get creative. Note that inputs A and E only appear in one term each, and they're never inverted. This means that you can connect BCD to the select inputs (B is the MSB) and create the desired function by connecting A to the 7 input and E to the 3 input. You also need to tie the 4 input high and all other inputs low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU5xGu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: how you chose A and E to be one of your inputs? I know to do that only if I have for example 8:1 mux with 4 paramters. so 3 goes to N-select and one of them will be one of my inputs depend the minterms

Comment: Ah , I see it now, B C D are found inside each expression so I can use them. thanks!